# Finding comma separated Strings in List<String>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a string list and I have a comma separated String.

I would like to do something like:

```
StringList.Contains(CommaSeparatedStrings);
```

So for example I have a list like:

```
StringList.Add(Admin);
StringList.Add(Nurse);
StringList.Add(Cook);

CommaSeparatedStrings = "Admin,Nurse";
```

So the above mentioned function should return true.

Comment: What should be the return value for "Admin,Cook"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `String.Split` to get a collection that you can use:

```
bool containsAny = StringList.Intersect(CommaSeparatedStrings.Split(',')).Any();
```

If you want to know if  *all* items (not only at least one) are contained:

```
bool containsAll = !CommaSeparatedStrings.Split(',').Except(StringList).Any();
```

or with `Enumerable.All` which seems to be the most readable way:

```
bool containsAll = CommaSeparatedStrings.Split(',').All(StringList.Contains);
```

Answer (score 1):

check if `CommaSeperatedStrings` splitted - `StringList` contains any value

```
bool contains = !CommaSeperatedStrings.Split(',').Except(StringList).Any()
```